# Cycle through array in class

Tags: php, arrays, class

I'm getting some really strange output from one of my classes, here:

```
class group
{
    public $myArray = array(); // an array of fraction objects

    // find the smallest fraction
    private function smallest()
    {
        $result = array('num'=>NULL, 'den'=>NULL); // this is what is returned
        // initialize temp variables
        $fractionObj = reset($this->myArray); // pointer to first element of array
        while($fractionObj->dropped == 1)
        {
            $fractionObj = next($this->myArray); // move the pointer ahead until finding a fraction that is not already dropped. RESULTS IN 'Notice: Trying to get property of non-object' ERROR on this line
        }
        $decimal = ($fractionObj->numerator/$fractionObj->denominator); // initialized to the first fraction value that is not dropped
        $result['num'] = $fractionObj->numerator;
        $result['den'] = $fractionObj->denominator;
        $lowest = $fractionObj;
        foreach($myArray as $a)
        {
            if($a->dropped == 0 && $a->numerator/$a->denominator < $decimal)
            {
                $decimal = $a->numerator/$a->denominator;
                $result['num'] = $a->numerator;
                $result['den'] = $a->denominator;
                $lowest->dropped = true; // mark this value as dropped so it is ignored for the next call to smallest()
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

class fraction
{
    public $numerator;
    public $denominator;
    public $dropped = false;
}
```

What I have here is a group class which contains an array of fraction class objects. When a new group object is created it is constructed with fractions being placed in the array and that all works fine.

I am trying to find the x number of smallest fractions (based on their decimal value) and mark the smallest ones as "dropped" meaning that they will still remain in the array but we will ignore them. That's what the $dropped variable indicates in the fraction class. I do this with a loop that calls the smallest() function

The problem is that I'm getting the notice that I'm trying to get a property of a non-object, ie $fractionObj->dropped. However, if I var_dump($fractionObj) it tells me that it IS an object. Is there a way to advance the array pointer to the next object in the array without using next() as I think this is the problem.

Comment: What line number is throwing the error?

Comment: Are you running the code as it is posted above? If so, the problem is that your array is empty. How do you populate $myArray with fraction objects?

Comment: You should check if $fractionObj is "false" since rest can return false if the array is empty.

Comment: Also, you didn't directly ask about this, but you might consider refactoring your code to give the fraction class more responsibility. Rather than dividing the numerator by the denominator in three different places, why not use something like `public function getDecimal() { return $this->numerator / $this->denominator; }`

Comment: @IPValverde The *reset* can return false if the array is empty.

Comment: @mkasberg, it's not empty. In my code I'm initializing the array. I use __construct() to populate. I didn't including this code because it would be way too long but I mentioned that in my question.

Comment: @mkasberg also, I did make a function like this. Also deprecated for simplicity.

I was able to solve this issue. I will post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve with the following solution. I'm sure better ways exist. It would have been really convenient to be able to iterate through with next() but I guess that doesn't work intuitively with objects.

```
class group
{
    public $myArray = array(); // an array of fraction objects

    // find the smallest fraction
    private function smallest()
        {
        $result = array('num'=>NULL, 'den'=>NULL); // this is what is returned
        foreach($this->myArray as $a)
        {
            if($a->dropped == false)
            {
                if(!isset($val))
                {
                    $val = $a->percent();
                    $lowest = $a;
                    $result['num'] = $a->nominator;
                    $result['den'] = $a->denominator;
                }else{
                    if($a->percent() < $val)
                    {
                        $val = $a->percent();
                        $lowest = $a;
                        $result['num'] = $a->nominator;
                        $result['den'] = $a->denominator;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $lowest->drop();
        return $result;
    }
}

class fraction
{
    public $numerator;
    public $denominator;
    public $dropped = false;

    public function percent()
    {
        return $this->numerator/$this->denominator;
    }

    public function drop()
    {
         $this->dropped = true;
    }
}
```